# Trying to get user authentication when creating a project in Visual Studio ASP.NET Mac

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-mac

I'm watching tutorials on how to implement user authentication in my MVC project and they all select "User Authentication" when creating the project. This is not an option on Visual Studio 2019 Mac for some reason and I don't know how to create this authentication without the template.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Why you think it is not possible on Mac? I dont get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... For some reason, Visual Studio for Mac does not have the option to create a project with Individual authentication. Don't ask me why, Microsoft is weird like that sometimes. However, you can use the CLI to create the project. That has the option for all the Identity class. 
Use the command

```
dotnet new mvc -o ProjectName --auth Individual
```

Add

```
-uld
```

in the auth option to use local db instead of SQLite.
Check out this link for more information.
[dotnet new command on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore22)
 Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

By default, VS2019 uses MS-SQL Server (or localdb which is also a cut down version of MS-SQL) as the data source for the authentication DB.

As far as I know (and I don't use or develop for Mac), MS-SQL or Localdb are not available in MacOS, so the option would not be there.

You can create your own data provider using SQLite but it doesn't seem particularly easy or friendly (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

I wish MS would include an option to use SQLite in their scaffolding...